# Monitor disk activity in Java

Tags: java, performance, android-activity, monitor, disk

I am looking for ways to monitor disk activity in a Java, closed-source, commercial, desktop application. In particular, what I'd like to do is monitor how frequently the app is accessing database/disk - it would appear as "HDD led" indicator in the app and would work exactly the same (so, essentially real-time activity monitoring). I would also like to have as little as possible external libraries.

What I've found so far, doesn't seem too encouraging - I haven't seen the exact examples of anything like that and the best hits I've managed to dig either reference huge frameworks (like Sigar) or libraries like JPicus (which doesn't support Java7 and doesn't seem like it'd support my case). JMX instrumentation doesn't seem to support this either, so I am pretty much open for any ideas/suggestions.

The tech stack is - Java7, Eclipse RCP, SQL Server 2008.

EDIT: To make matters totally clear, I want to monitor disk I/O activity of a Java program with a pure, platform agnostic Java solution.

Comment: Do you need to monitor disk activity of other processes, or just your own process?  Is the database a separate process?

Comment: Could you use strace (linux) or procmon (windows)?

Comment: It's an app using MS SQL Server, so Linux is out of equation. I need to monitor my own process only - more specifically, I need to monitor how frequently the JVM (which runs my application) accesses the disk. So, essentially, I just need to see how frequently the app hits the disk. To answer the second comment - I'd rather not rely on external tools but if that would ease the implementation, I would be willing to think about it. That being said, I found mentions of JNI used to access some low-level Windows API calls/functions - that, I'd like to avoid as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know how to monitor the disk I/O activity of a windows process: please ask that question on server fault.

If you want to know how to monitor disk I/O activity of a Java program with a pure, platform agnostic Java solution: There is none, especially meeting your requirements. Technically the only option would be to wrap all I/O operations with instrumented code, which is rather costly.

Comment: Thank you for your post - I've edited the original question to be totally clear about it. Let's suppose I am willing to consider JNI calls - do you have anything to propose?

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the implementation of FileInputStream/FileOutputStream with classes in an extension directory. If that isn't picked up early enough, try setting `java.system.class.loader` to your own classloader that can intercept requests for those classes.

Comment: It's not just the disk file operations I am interested - it's *any* disk activity, be it file ops, database or something totally different. Nevertheless, thanks for replying.